# Looking for an episode of a 90's show involving a man who can time travel after having a car accident

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

So, I remember those moments:

A man had a car accident. After that he is able to travel through time. Every time he travels he sort of hallucinates and he is in some sort of a huge cave with a some sort of a lake (a reddish, foggy lake). In this lake there's a monster, it looks like a giant claw. The man has to avoid the claw and reach the shore.

I watched it like 10 years ago and might confuse details. I was sure it's *The Outer Limits*, but there's no episode like this. I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 4):

This is an episode of [The Outer Limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_%281995_TV_series%29), Season 2 of the new series entitled [Vanishing Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_Act_%28The_Outer_Limits%29).

The protagonist gets in a car crash and disappears for 10 years. He is taken by some form of aliens to their reality where time moves faster.