# Show Identification: Every time the man sleeps he wakes up years later

Tags: story-identification

This is a show (or short movie) I recall from my childhood. Some details may be inaccurate, but here's what I recall:

- protagonist is a male
- Plot: Protagonist is a truck with another man. The other man shows the protagonist something creepy. They get into a wreck. The protagonist wakes alone, and the truck he was riding is covered in overgrown foliage. The protagonist returns home to find out it has changed. He eventually reunites with his family, and they discover each time he sleeps X years pass by, without the protagonist aging. The protagonists (ex)wife eventually remarries and her new husband helps come up with a theory that the protagonist is being abducted by aliens.
- Probably black and white. At one point I thought this was a twilight zone episode, but after binge watching on Netflix I could not identify it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not black and white, this sounds pretty close to the episode of The Outer Limits (1995 version) called "[Vanishing Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_Act_(The_Outer_Limits))"

In it, the main character is abducted by aliens and every time he goes to sleep, he awakens ten years ahead in the future.

As you can see [here](https://youtu.be/1-9pOLbxkkg?t=76), in the first two minutes there is indeed a scene early on where he is in a truck, gets in an accident, and wakes up in the car ten years later, and a little [later](https://youtu.be/1-9pOLbxkkg?t=1757) (around the 29 minute mark) a scene where his wife's new husband theorizes aliens and wormholes involved in his dilemma.

Comment: If this is the answer this question might considered a duplicate of [this older one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100084/101407) though this question is better written.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely the show I was thinking about.

Comment: You made some good points about the some wrong details. Such as Black & white, also apparently I'm confusing another show regarding the two men in the truck and the other shows the guy something creepy. Is it appropriate to update these details on the question for this stack exchange ?